# Why i can't pass variables with my function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have this code in my react native app that is using firebase :

```js
let bestTutors = [];

const getBestTutors = async () => {
    const snapshot = await getDoc(docRef);
    bestTutors = snapshot.data().list;
}

getBestTutors();

console.log(bestTutors);
```

But when i run it it only console logs "Array[ ]", I've tried to using .then( ) and all kind other stuff that doesn't make sense for me, idk if there's a wey to use it without the await or How can i pass the data to the variable :( ?

Comment: You need to await getBestTutors()

Comment: Try to use var instead of let. I think the problem is in area.

Comment: @tokkerbaz no, that doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

call function with await. Like this one

```js
await getBestTutors()
```

Comment: Providing code example with formatting is easier for others to refer.

Answer (score 1):

Look at my comments

Your Code 1

```js
let bestTutors = [];

const getBestTutors = async () => {
    const snapshot = await getDoc(docRef);
    bestTutors = snapshot.data().list;
}

getBestTutors(); // Asynchronous function

console.log(bestTutors); // this is called before getBestTutors() returns the data. So console.log(bestTutors) return de default value: []
```

The new code

```js
let bestTutors = [];

const getBestTutors = async () => {
    const snapshot = await getDoc(docRef);
    bestTutors = snapshot.data().list;
}

await getBestTutors(); // Wait until getBestTutors() has finished and then Next.

console.log(bestTutors);
```

Comment: I tought his was supposed to fix it but i gives me this error : "Unexpected identifier 'getBestTutors'

Comment: here is the full code where i use it: https://codeshare.io/Wdk9WW